# split list elements into sublists based on character in list element

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
['AA/usermanagedmanualreport',
'AccountingDocuments/BPC/COPA/NGAP/Tableau',
'AccountingDocuments/BW',
'AccountingDocuments/DOMS/POS/RFS/SAPBPC/COPA/NGAP/Tableau',
'AccountsPayable/Akritiv']
```

I'm trying to get it like this:

```
['AA/usermanagedmanualreport',
'AccountingDocuments/BPC',
'AccountingDocuments/COPA',
'AccountingDocuments/NGAP',
'AccountingDocuments/Tableau',
'AccountingDocuments/BW',
'AccountingDocuments/DOMS',
'AccountingDocuments/POS',
'AccountingDocuments/RFS',
'AccountingDocuments/SAPBPC',
'AccountingDocuments/COPA',
'AccountingDocuments/NGAP',
'AccountingDocuments/Tableau',
'AccountsPayable/Akritiv']
```

I basically just need to split each list element in to separate elements based on the first value in the list and the "/" separator.

Tried something like this but it doesn't do quite what I want:

```
[l.split('/') for l in ','.join(myList).split('|')]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the general logic? If you have multiple '/' in same string you must join the first part with all other parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a loop:

```py
parts = []
for x in myList:
    first, *rest = x.split("/")
    parts += [first + "/" + part for part in rest]

print(parts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
l=['AA/usermanagedmanualreport',
'AccountingDocuments/BPC/COPA/NGAP/Tableau',
'AccountingDocuments/BW',
'AccountingDocuments/DOMS/POS/RFS/SAPBPC/COPA/NGAP/Tableau',
'AccountsPayable/Akritiv']

def div(x):
    s=x.split('/')
    first=s[0]
    rest=s[1:]
    return [first+'/'+i for i in rest]

res=[]
for i in l:
    if i.count('/')<2:
        res.append(i)
    else:
        res.extend(div(i))

>>>print(res)

['AA/usermanagedmanualreport', 'AccountingDocuments/BPC', 'AccountingDocuments/COPA', 'AccountingDocuments/NGAP', 'AccountingDocuments/Tableau', 'AccountingDocuments/BW', 'AccountingDocuments/DOMS', 'AccountingDocuments/POS', 'AccountingDocuments/RFS', 'AccountingDocuments/SAPBPC', 'AccountingDocuments/COPA', 'AccountingDocuments/NGAP', 'AccountingDocuments/Tableau', 'AccountsPayable/Akritiv']
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner for fun:

```
>>> l = ['AA/usermanagedmanualreport',
...      'AccountingDocuments/BPC/COPA/NGAP/Tableau',
...      'AccountingDocuments/BW',
...      'AccountingDocuments/DOMS/POS/RFS/SAPBPC/COPA/NGAP/Tableau',
...      'AccountsPayable/Akritiv']
>>> result = [f'{a}/{x}' for a, *b in (item.split('/') for item in l) for x in b]
>>> print(*result, sep='\n')
AA/usermanagedmanualreport
AccountingDocuments/BPC
AccountingDocuments/COPA
AccountingDocuments/NGAP
AccountingDocuments/Tableau
AccountingDocuments/BW
AccountingDocuments/DOMS
AccountingDocuments/POS
AccountingDocuments/RFS
AccountingDocuments/SAPBPC
AccountingDocuments/COPA
AccountingDocuments/NGAP
AccountingDocuments/Tableau
AccountsPayable/Akritiv
```